# Select Rows Between 2 Dates in SQlite3 Database

Tags: python, date, sqlite, between

from the following database I want to select with SQlite3 all the rows that have >700 Day_Minutes and are in between the Dates 2017-10-14 and 2017-10-12

```
DATE            DAY_MINUTES
"2017-10-11"    "570"
"2017-10-11"    "615"
"2017-10-11"    "675"
"2017-10-11"    "715"
"2017-10-12"    "545"
"2017-10-12"    "665"
"2017-10-12"    "685"
"2017-10-12"    "725"
"2017-10-13"    "545"
"2017-10-13"    "605"
"2017-10-13"    "665"
"2017-10-13"    "725"
"2017-10-14"    "535"
"2017-10-14"    "605"
"2017-10-14"    "685"
"2017-10-14"    "775"
"2017-10-15"    "535"
"2017-10-15"    "605"
"2017-10-15"    "685"
"2017-10-15"    "725"
```

The result should be in this case as follow:

```
DATE            DAY_MINUTES
"2017-10-12"    "725"
"2017-10-13"    "725"
"2017-10-14"    "775"
```

I tried the following two (to start selecting at least all the dates between the period) with no success just to realise that I do not know how those SQL statements really work.

```
pd.read_sql_query('''
            SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(create_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
            FROM    {0}
            WHERE   create_date BETWEEN {1} - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND {1}
        '''.format(file_name, startdate), conn)
```

and

```
pd.read_sql_query('''
            SELECT * FROM {0}
            WHERE DATE between '2017-09-11' and '2017-08-29'
            '''.format(file_name, startdate), conn)
```

would appreciate a solution or just a targeted source where I can learn to understand those statements. thanks!

if there is a way to do the above with only one column the like of:

```
DATE
"2017-09-11 11:40"
```

even better

EDIT:
After a little read of W3school I understood I was putting dates in the wrong order.
For dates selection this worked:

```
SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2017-08-11' AND '2017-09-11';
```

so there is no need to specify any date format, which is what was confusing me

still have to figure out how to select only the rows with day_minutes >700

Comment: You can check W3school for basic SQL query .

Comment: thanks, that was very usefull, it gave me the few information I needed to understand my mistake.. don't ask me why my google search did not bring me to W3school. anyway I was simply putting dates in the wrong order

Comment: Well.. the last bit... you just add "AND day_minutes > 700" to your where clause, no?

Comment: Thanks! I was getting there I swear :D